# How to "scope" event listeners?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is my code:

```
var myFunction(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", self.onDeviceReady, false); // scoped event listener
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As far as I see when the event (`deviceready`) is triggered, the local (to `myFunction`) callback is run.

However the event listeners is global so another function with the same with global scope may be called as well, once the event is triggered.

**How to make not only the callback, but the listener itself locally scoped to a function (I know how to do it for a DOM element but that's different)?**

Comment: `self.onDeviceReady` is incorrect - it should just be `onDeviceReady`. And that's not how event handler binding works; it has nothing to do with the name of the function, but with the value of the function as an object.

Answer (score 2):

Elements themselves are scoped globally. As soon as you attach something to them, they are scoped that way. Consider the following ::

```
function myfunc(){
    document.getElementById('someId').something = 'test';
}
```

This will now be accessed everywhere.

I see what you want to get at so you could try several things. Here is something you could try. This will check to see if an event already exists for an element and not let you add another.

```js
var Marvel = {
  
 on : function(element, action, callback){
  Marvel.listeners = Marvel.listeners || {};
  Marvel.listeners[action] = Marvel.listeners[action] || [];
  for(var index in Marvel.listeners[action]){
   if(Marvel.listeners[action][index].element == element){
    return console.error("A '"+action+"' event is already established for:", element, Marvel.listeners[action][index]), false
   }
  }
  element.addEventListener(action,callback);
  Marvel.listeners[action].push({ element: element, callback: callback });
 },
  
 off: function(element, action){
  if(!Marvel.listeners || !Marvel.listeners[action])
   return console.error("off: No '"+action+"' listener has been created. Listeners: ", Marvel.listeners || 'none'), false;
  for(var index in Marvel.listeners[action]){
   if(Marvel.listeners[action][index].element == element){
    element.removeEventListener(action, Marvel.listeners[action][index].callback);
    Marvel.listeners[action].splice(index, 1);
    return true
   }
  }
  return console.error("A '"+action+"' event has not yet been established for:", element, Marvel.listeners[action]), false;
 }
  
}
```

Usage:

```
Marvel.on(document, click, function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
});
Marvel.off(document, click);
```

This sets an event listener to be stored in a separate object and checks to see if it already exists when adding new ones, and additionally allows the capability to have an `off` function to turn them off.

You can find the full explanation for this on my site in my profile in the Javascript Tracking Events section.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this :

```
function myFunction() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
       //...
    }, false); // scoped event listener
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a declared function as an event handler.

Comment: @Pointy Read the first post. `var myFunction() {`

Comment: Yes well there are many things wrong with that code :)  I can't really tell what it is that the OP is worried about.